# Как выровнять форму по центру?

Tags: python, html, css, django

Есть форма:

```
<div class="teams_form">
    <form action="/" method='POST' class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
        {{ form.as_p }}
        {% csrf_token %}
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
 .teams_form {
     margin: 50px ;
 }
```

Как вывести ее по центру ?

Answer (score 0):

Немного не понятно, что именно надо выровнять, если объекты внутри формы, то вот пример. Если в целом форму которая в div, то margin:0 auto; впиши к верхнему диву

```
<div class="teams_form">
  <div class="test>
    <form action="/" method='POST' class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
        {{ form.as_p }}
        {% csrf_token %}
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.test{margin:0 auto;}
```

Comment: А зачем ещё один DIV создавать то...?

Comment: Смотря что вам нужно выровнять. Если не внутренние элементы, а форму в целом. То вам нужно создать div поверх teams_form

<div class="test">
<div class="teams_form">

    <form action="/" method='POST' class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
        {{ form.as_p }}
        {% csrf_token %}
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>

</div>
</div>

Comment: form { display: block; margin: 0 auto; }, форма выровнена

Answer (score 0):

Форму поместить в **div** и для него прописать `margin:auto;`